# Error in gradle with facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

Try to add Facebook SDK to project `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'` and i always got

```
E:\Work\hotel\generic\hotelClient\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\com_facebook_close.png: error: Duplicate file.
E:\Work\hotel\generic\hotelClient\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi\com_facebook_close.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
Error:Execution failed for task ':hotelClient:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\pavel.shkaran\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I've tried to clean project, rebuild project and delete build folder.

Comment: The error is pretty clear that there are two resource files with the same name causing the problem. "com_facebook_close.png" Do you by chance have an asset called that or did you originally add the Facebook SDK as a lib instead of as gradle dependency? Or perhaps there is a bug in that version of Facebook SDK? Try newer version? I think they are at v4.8.2 now.

Comment: @MichaelGarner with new one library i have this one `Error:cannot access Utility$3 `

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. You would need to include full stacktrace if there is any hope of me helping. Is this error occurring at build time? Is it preventing you from building?